# Excel User Form - How to code the Command Button to enter a Value of True when Clicked and value of False when not clicked?

Tags: vba, excel, commandbutton

I'm new to VBA Programming but I have started to learn the basics. I am a Trader in the Futures Markets so I'm building a userform to assist with record-keeping.

My userform with a <kbd>Save</kbd> button seems to correctly populate the relevant cells.  My problem is with the Command Buttons:

**When clicked, the <kbd>Save</kbd> button will:**

1. Ensure the user completed all required fields
2. When properly completed, it will add the data to the relevant cells in the next empty row.

Command buttons are named `Long`, `Short`, `Yes`, `No`, and buttons in the `Filters` Frame etc.  I'm trying to get it so:

- The relevant cell should contain `FALSE` **until the button is clicked**, then it should change to `TRUE`.

For example, if I click Long, there is no data on the worksheet currently, so `D3` (under the `Long` Header) should be `TRUE`. Then, when I enter a different set of data, and do *not* click `Long`, it should show `FALSE` in perhaps `D4` (the next row because data would be in the previous row...and so on).

I was unsuccessful at solving this on my own with online research.  I'd appreciate help learning to code 1 command button, then the rest will be easy.

**My naming convention is:**

- **Text Boxes**: `tbMkt`, `tbEntryPrice`, `tbStopLoss`, `tbTargetPrice` etc.
- **Buttons**: `btnLong`, `btnShort`, `btnYesTrend`, `btnNoTrend`, `btnFilter1`, `btnFilter2`, `btnFilter3`.

**Additional Information: Code**

```
Option Explicit
Public myGlobalVar As Boolean
Private Sub btnClose_Click()
    Me.Hide
    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub btnLong_Click()
    myGlobalVar = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click()

    Me.Hide


    If tbMkt.Value = "" Or tbEntry = "" Or tbStopLoss = "" Or tbTarget = "" Then
        If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If


    Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = tbMkt.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = tbDate.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = tbTime.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = btnLong.Visible

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = tbEntry.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = tbStopLoss.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = tbTarget.Value

    MsgBox "Thank You for entering the details of your trade. They have been added to row " & ActiveCell.Row
    Unload Me

    Call resetForm

    Me.tbDate = Date
    tbDate.Value = Format(tbDate.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Me.tbTime = Time

End Sub

Sub resetForm()

    tbMkt.Value = ""
    tbDate.Value = ""
    tbTime.Value = ""
    tbEntry.Value = ""


    tbStopLoss.Value = ""
    tbTarget.Value = ""
    tradeEntryUserForm.tbMkt.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.tbDate = Date
    tbDate.Value = Format(tbDate.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Me.tbTime = Time

End Sub

Private Sub WithTrendFrame_Click()

End Sub
```

I have declared myGlobalVar as per the above code. I have set this to True in the btnLong_Click() but I am unsure what you mean by step 2 loading the event set to False on the form? Please help.

### Hope I'm doing the correct thing by editing to add more information around my question...

**User Form:**

[image: User Form]

**Worksheet:**

[image: Excel worksheet]

Comment: Post your code, not as an image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I didn't intend to re-write your whole question, but it's important to keep questions short and to-the-point.  As you can see, both the images and text convey the same question but in half the amount of reading time for potential assistance.  That being said, I see you got an answer before I even finished editing!  It's good to include all the relevant information, but this is also an important read: [mcve].  Good luck!

Comment: ...and that's the only thing I couldn't fix -- it's better if you post actual code instead of an image; that way others can copy and paste it as required while trying to help you.  If the answer below is suitable, don't worry about replacing the code this time. Otherwise, you can [edit] your question.  Lines automatically become `code blocks` when you indent them with four spaces, or else highlight the code and click the `{ }` code button.

Comment: IM removing my down vote b/c your color code schema on your user form is visually pleasurable

Comment: So, even though I read through the question repeatedly I'm still not entirely clear on the order of events...  Is this correct:  1. Any time you open the form the next empty row should be populated with `FALSE`, which is will stay until a button click validates user input, and then the last `FALSE` should change to TRUE (and nothing else needs to change it again after it's TRUE, correct?

Comment: @Shyam THe load event for the form can be found in the design view. Oen up the visual basic editor, find the form and right click design view. Click on the form and use the upper right hand drop down. Should have a load event. For excel vba it might be called "Initialize" -  the various object models sometimes interchange the terminologies.

Comment: Thanks. @ashleedawg yes. Once The form opens, it should have a default value of False in that empty cell. Until the user clicks the button, Long, it should change that value to True. However, i do not want the value to change back to False when the form closes. The save button will work as normal. So to answer your question, correct.

Comment: Hi all, thanks very much for your help. This has really helped and I have completed my form that works perfectly as I wanted :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is really easy.

1) Set a global variable of boolean type

2) on form load event set to false

3) on button click event set to true

4) figure out where in the process the value should be reset if necessary

ALso because you call a function called "Reset form" just be aware that if youre reloading the form, that per my description, if followed, that it will reset the value of the boolean variable (might be intentional but thats up to you to decide).

Comment: wow, you answered the question is less time than it took me to edit the question closer to being a [mcve]...  :)

Comment: @ashleedawg well If i had saw your edits before, maybe he wouldnt have gotten down voted :|

Comment: I meant it more in the "this is stupid easy" not in the way like "this is so easy your stupid." But fine youre right hold on....

Comment: I kinda wanna edit more.  I guess I'd be going overboard if I reduced it to 6 words total?  *`"Change FALSE to TRUE with Button?"`*  -- speaking of which, I believe Boolean defaults to FALSE so the on_load event wouldn't be required either, right?

Comment: @ashleedawg LOL eh "play big or go home."

Comment: Doug - *hmm, ur*  *2, **eh**?*

Comment: '@ashleedawg "eh" as in "eh whatever, sure," eh :D phonetically pronounced "eh" instead of "ay"

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorry, still very new to Stackoverflow. I have just added additional comments @DougCoats. Hoping you can help with this. I'm very new to VBA itself too. Thanks in advance.